# Blazor WebAssembly - how to securely consume private/restricted API?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I want to build 2 apps.

1. Private API in .NET that takes care of database access / processing of data.
2. Blazor WebAssembly app which will connect to this API securely, to search data.

Since Blazor WebAssembly DLLs can be decompiled, I can't use any private/secret keys in the APP.
I don't want anyone being able to use the API if they discover the endpoints. Only the Blazor APP can use the API (and any other app I might build in the future).

How should I approach this? Is it even possible to do it securely or should I go Server Side?

Answer (score 1):

[Secure ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) explains how to secure a Blazor WASM app

[Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Preview 2 release now available](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/) explains how to use `IAccessTokenProvider` to get the access token to authentify your applicaton on API.